# Как использовать CSS внутри PHP? Или как обойти

Tags: php, css

Дкло вот в чем. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на submit выполнялось

```
 if($sql){
     #title -> z-index: -1;
 }
```

Т.е, если удачно, то z-index #title сделать -1. Поискал в интернете, но не нашел подходящий вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сначала определите в css

```
#title { z-index: -1; }
```

Потом в php:

```
$zIndex = $sql ? true : false;
```

или

```
$zIndex = $sql;
```

в шаблоне пропишите что-нибудь такое:

```
<h1 <?php echo $zIndex ? 'id="title"' : ''; ?>>Заголовок</h1>
```

Ну как-то так